# setting dropdown selected value for next page

Tags: jquery, html, session, drop-down-menu

I have drop down select box and I am getting values dynamically ,

```
<select style='width: 200px;' id="combo_zone11" name="alfa1">
<c:forEach var="grade" items="${gradeInfo}">
  <option id='syear' value="" selected="selected">
      <option value=${grade.getDropDownId()}>${grade.getDropDownName()}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

I stored it in session variable, to test I am displaying session attribute(drop down selected value) somewhere in next page as

```
<c:out value="${schoolYear}"></c:out>
```

its fine its displaying. But in this page I am trying to set this value as selected value of drop down. for that I did ,

```
<select style='width: 200px;'id="combo_zone11" name="alfa1">
  <c:forEach var="grade" items="${gradeInfo}">
<option id='syear' value="${schoolYear}" selected="selected">
<option value=${grade.getDropDownId()} >${grade.getDropDownName()}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

but I cant able to set it as selected how to do this can anyone please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the option text. also you have not closed option. you need to use:

```
if(${schoolYear}==${grade.getDropDownId()})
  <option value="${schoolYear}" selected="selected">${schoolYear}</option>
else
  <option value="${schoolYear}">${schoolYear}</option>
```

Comment: but it is in loop rt, so in values is repeating . .

Comment: which one you want to select?? also your code will create option with duplicate id which is incorrect.

Comment: it is like adding one more value to drop down. but I dont want like this, I want to compare `${schoolYear}` with `${grade.getDropDownId()}` if it is equal set that value as selected.

Comment: k . . remove id i dont want id , id is not needed to me

Comment: thanks dude I got it, but in jsp we cant use `if() else` directly so I use `<c:choose>` and `<c:when>`

Comment: @user3599482: i am unaware with that syntax. plese update the answer so it would be helpful for others referring the post in future.

Answer (score 0):

Here to compare value of `${schoolYear}` and `${grade.getDropDownId()}` we can use if else, but in jsp we have `<c:choose>` and '` for that. Here is the correct format of using it,

```
<select style='width: 200px;' >
<c:forEach var="grade" items="${gradeInfo}">
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${grade.getDropDownId()==schoolYear}">
  <option value=${grade.getDropDownId()}selected="selected">${grade.getDropDownName()}</option>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
  <option value=${grade.getDropDownId()}>${grade.getDropDownName()}</option>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

This will give the correct values.